# UITableViewCell Background Color is a different shade at left and right edges of cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibackgroundcolor

I'm setting the background color of a cell in tableview:willDisplayCell and I'm getting the color I want. However, the left and right edges of the cell are a different shade and I'm not sure why. Does anyone have any ideas why the shade of the background color would be different on the edges of the cell? Thanks

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.9333333 green:.46666667 blue:.43137225 alpha:0.5];

}
```

Comment: Did you set the background color of the table as well? If you dont do that as well, this can cause weird color pairs because the table is one color, while the cells are another color

Comment: Are there subviews on your UITableViewCell on the left and right edges? Views, labels, etc.?

Comment: I didn't do that at first, but I just did and no luck. I went ahead and tried setting the tableview, tableviewcell, and cell content view to the same background color, but I still have two vertical bars of a different shade running along the side of my tableview. Thanks for your advice

Comment: hw731 good call. I didn't think about the subviews, because I thought that setting the cell's background color would fill the whole cell. But there textLabel view(which is a default subview of UITableViewCell) appears to be the culprit. When I set the background color of it to match my cell, the bars went away. I am still a little confused as to the why, but it worked. Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2):

After a little bit of experimentation and hw731's suggestion to look at my subviews, I found out why I was experiencing this. In the code I shared, you'll notice that I set the alpha to 0.5, because initially this view was going to have a bit of transparency. Doing so allowed the background color of the cell's textLabel to show through a bit on the sides, making it a different shade than the rest of the cell. There were two things I found that could fix it. I could keep the transparency of the cell's background color at 0.5, but to do so I had to also set cell.textLabel.backgroundColor to the desired color. What I ended up doing is just reverting back to an alpha of 1.0 so I didn't have to worry about it. So it looks to me as if the problem was just a matter of subviews showing through since I set my alpha below 1.0. I'm sure someone could explain this better than me, and if so, feel free. Hope this helps someone else!