# UITableView - nested background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've setup a custom class which extends UITableViewCell to try and style a table in an IOS app  - I have the following code -

```
 - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
   {
   [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

if(selected){
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255.0) green:(128/255.0) blue:(37/255.0) alpha:0.5]];

     self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }
    else{
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(142/255.0) green:(141/255.0) blue:(139/255.0) alpha:1];

     }
    }
```

I would like the selected background color to be an opaque version of the orange used throughout our app - but the result of my code looks like below -

[image]

the centre piece of the cell becomes a darker version of the same color!?  Can anybody please explain.

Also - as an extra query - Is it possible to apply a opaque shade of white to the entire background of the unselected version of the cell?

FOLLOW UP -

Having followed the advice of Maros I've added the following to my styledcell.M file -

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
```

self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

but i'm still getting the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working - for some reason the text label had inherited the same background color so the two opaque colors on top of one another gave the above effect -

i removed via -

```
 self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Having notied the comments on this SO bug -
[UITableViewCell Background Color is a different shade at left and right edges of cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089537/uitableviewcell-background-color-is-a-different-shade-at-left-and-right-edges-of)

Answer (score 1):

Set the UITableViewCell's UITableViewCellSelectionStyle to be UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone.

in `awakeFromNib` or `initWithFrame:` method at your custom UITableViewCell Class add this line:

```
  self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

I think that this selection style overdraws the background of the tableview.

Comment: do i need to apply a awakeFromNib or initWithFrame method to my custom cell class to apply this then?  ive tried - (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}  but no luck!

Comment: @Dancer depends how you load your cell. e.g. awakeFromNib is called when you load the cell from nib. You can also add it to the  `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated` method. But it will be called unnecessary every time the cell is selected. What is ok, in the end.

Comment: the cell has its own custom class - styledcell.m - i hav tried adding initwithframe (it only has the standard initwithstyle and setselected methods) - and applied the above - but no luck!

Comment: @Dancer so you added this line `self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` into the `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated` and it didn't work?

Comment: yeah - ive added it in there - proper pain in a33, I cant figure it out at all

Comment: file looks like this
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
     self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

Comment: @Dancer ah ok, can you try to add it to the: ` - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ` { ... cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; ... } of your UITableViewController ?

Comment: cheers for your help Maros, gave it a go - still got the same issue though - annoying problem!